# Simulating MIPS processor on FPGA using Verilog

Tags: simulation, mips, verilog, fpga, hdl

I am trying to simulate a simple MIPS processor on an FPGA using Verilog. Here is my code:

```
module MIPS_Processor(output reg[7:0] LEDs, input[7:0] Switches);
    reg [31:0] memory[0:4095];   // 4K memory cells that are 32 bits wide
    reg [31:0] code[0:1023];     // 1K memory cells that are 32 bits wide
    reg [31:0] registers[0:31];  // 32 registers that are 32 bits wide
    reg [31:0] PC;               // The program counter

    reg [31:0] instruction;
    reg [5 :0] op;
    reg [4 :0] rs;
    reg [4 :0] rt;
    reg [4 :0] rd;
    reg [4 :0] shamt;
    reg [5 :0] funct;
    reg signed [15:0] immediate_offset;
    reg [25:0] target;

    reg [1:0] instruction_type; // 00 --> R | 01 --> I | 10 --> J | 11 --> EXTRA

    reg [31:0] rs_value;
    reg [31:0] rt_value;
    reg [31:0] rd_value;

    initial
        begin
            PC = 0;

            /* Here we insert the code in the code array */
            code[0] = 32'b00010010000000000000000000000000; // start : input  s0   # read switches.
            code[1] = 32'b00010010000000000000000000000001; //         output s0   # write leds.
            code[2] = 32'b00001000000000000000000000000000; //         j      start
            code[3] = 32'b00000100000000000000000000000000; // END OF CODE
        end

    always
        begin : loop_block
            // 1. Fetch an instruction from memory
            instruction = code[PC];

            // 2. Increment the program counter register (by the instruction length)
            PC = PC + 1;

            // 3. Decode the instruction
            /*
                The instructions are:
                                            6   5    5    5    5    6
                                           _____________________________
                or    rd, rs, rt           | 0 | rs | rt | rd | 0 | 0x25 |

                                             6    5    5        16
                                           _____________________________
                ori  rt, rs, immediate    | 0xd | rs | rt |  immediate  |

                                            6   5    5    5    5    6
                                           _____________________________
                and  rd, rs, rt           | 0 | rs | rt | rd | 0 | 0x24 |

                                             6    5    5        16
                                           _____________________________
                andi rt, rs, immediate    | 0xc | rs | rt |  immediate  |

                                            6   5    5         16
                                           _____________________________
                beq  rs, rt, offset       | 4 | rs | rt |    offset     |

                                            6   5    5    5    5    6
                                           _____________________________
                sub  rd, rs, rt           | 0 | rs | rt | rd | 0 | 0x22 |

                                            6   5    5    5    5    6
                                           _____________________________
                add  rd, rs, rt           | 0 | rs | rt | rd | 0 | 0x20 |

                                            6    5    5       16
                                           _____________________________
                addi rt, rs, immediate    | 8 | rs | rt |   immediate   |

                                            6             26
                                           _____________________________
                j    target               | 2 |         target          |

                                            6   5    5    5    5    6
                                           _____________________________
                slt  rd, rs, rt           | 0 | rs | rt | rd | 0 | 0x2a |

                                             6     5    5        16
                                           _____________________________
                lw   rt, rs[offset]       | 0x23 | rs | rt |   offset   |

                                             6     5    5        16
                                           _____________________________
                sw   rt, rs[offset]       | 0x2b | rs | rt |   offset   |


                ::EXTRA INSTRUCTIONS::

                                            6    5            21
                                           _____________________________
                input  rs                 | 4 |  rs  |        0         |

                                            6    5            21
                                           _____________________________
                output rs                 | 4 |  rs  |        1         |

            */
            op[5:0] = instruction[31:26];
            case(op)
                0: /* R-type */
                    begin
                        rs = instruction[25:21];
                        rt = instruction[20:16];
                        rd = instruction[15:11];
                        shamt = instruction[10:6];
                        funct = instruction[5:0];
                        instruction_type = 2'b00;
                    end

                1: /* END OF CODE */
                    begin
                        disable loop_block;
                    end

                2: /* J-type */
                    begin
                        target = instruction[25:0];
                        instruction_type = 2'b10;
                    end

                4: /* EXTRA */
                   begin
                        rs = instruction[25:21];
                        funct = instruction[20:0];
                        instruction_type = 2'b11;
                    end

                default: /* I-type */
                    begin
                        rs = instruction[25:21];
                        rt = instruction[20:16];
                        immediate_offset = instruction[15:0];
                        instruction_type = 2'b01;
                    end
            endcase


            // 4. Fetch operands, if any, usually from registers
            case(instruction_type)
                2'b00: /* R-type */
                    begin
                        rs_value = registers[rs];
                        rt_value = registers[rt];
                    end

                2'b01: /* I-type */
                    begin
                        rs_value = registers[rs];
                    end
                2'b11: /* EXTRA */
                    begin
                        if(funct == 1) rs_value = registers[rs];
                    end
            endcase

            // 5. Perform the operation
            case(instruction_type)
                2'b00: /* R-type */
                    begin
                        case(funct)
                            2'h20: /* add  rd, rs, rt */
                                begin
                                    rd_value = rs_value + rt_value;
                                end
                            2'h22: /* sub  rd, rs, rt */
                                begin
                                    rd_value = rs_value - rt_value;
                                end
                            2'h24: /* and  rd, rs, rt */
                                begin
                                    rd_value = rs_value & rt_value;
                                end
                            2'h25: /* or    rd, rs, rt */
                                begin
                                    rd_value = rs_value | rt_value;
                                end
                            2'h2a: /* slt  rd, rs, rt */
                                begin
                                    rd_value = rs_value < rt_value? 1 : 0;
                                end
                        endcase
                    end

                2'b01: /* I-type */
                    begin
                        case(op)
                            4: /* beq  rs, rt, offset */
                                begin
                                    if(rs_value < rt_value) PC = immediate_offset;
                                end
                            8: /* addi rt, rs, immediate */
                                begin
                                    rt_value = rs_value + immediate_offset;
                                end
                            1'hc: /* andi rt, rs, immediate */
                                begin
                                    rt_value = rs_value & immediate_offset;
                                end
                            1'hd: /* ori  rt, rs, immediate */
                                begin
                                    rt_value = rs_value | immediate_offset;
                                end
                            2'h23: /* lw   rt, rs[offset] */
                                begin
                                    rt_value = memory[rs + immediate_offset];
                                end
                            2'h2b: /* sw   rt, rs[offset] */
                                begin
                                    memory[rs + immediate_offset] = rt_value;
                                end
                        endcase
                    end

                2'b10: /* J-type */
                    begin
                        case(op)
                            2: /* j    target */
                                begin
                                    PC = target;
                                end
                        endcase
                    end

                2'b11: /* EXTRA */
                    begin
                        case(funct)
                            0: /* input  rs */
                                begin
                                    rs_value[7:0] = Switches;
                                end

                            1: /* output rs */
                                begin
                                    LEDs = rs_value[7:0];
                                end
                        endcase
                        if(funct == 1) rs_value = registers[rs];
                    end
            endcase

            // 6. Store the results
            case(instruction_type)
                2'b00: /* R-type */
                    begin
                        registers[rd] = rd_value;
                    end
                2'b01: /* I-type */
                    begin
                        case(op)
                            8: /* addi rt, rs, immediate */
                                begin
                                    registers[rt] = rt_value;
                                end
                            1'hc: /* andi rt, rs, immediate */
                                begin
                                    registers[rt] = rt_value;
                                end
                            1'hd: /* ori  rt, rs, immediate */
                                begin
                                    registers[rt] = rt_value;
                                end
                            2'h23: /* lw   rt, rs[offset] */
                                begin
                                    registers[rt] = rt_value;
                                end
                        endcase
                    end
                2'b11: /* EXTRA */
                    begin
                        if(funct == 0) registers[rs] = rs_value;
                    end
            endcase

            #100; /* Delay */

        end
endmodule
```

I have attched `output reg[7:0] LEDs` to 8 LEDs on the FPGA device, and `input[7:0] Switches` on 8 switches of the FPGA. The code is compiled without any error. But unfortunately, it doesn't work. The LEDs should show the states of the switches, but they are always turned off.

However, when I tried hardcode the LEDs states like `LEDs[7:0] = 8'b11111111;` inside the `initial` block, the LEDs stays turned on all the time. While when I placed `LEDs[7:0] = 8'b11111111;` inside the `always` block, the LEDs stays turned off all the time. It seems that the FPGA does not execute the code inside `always` block, what is wrong? Am I implementing the design in a wrong way?

Comment: If I understand you, you're trying to place this into an actual FPGA... I'm no hw engineer, but -- where's your clock to drive the always block? You use `#100` but that is notsynthesizable... so I don't think your always block can run in hardware. (Again -- I'm no hw engineer, and also my Verilog experiences is limited and ancient.) Beyond that, if I were in your shoes I would attach the `instruction` register to outputs which I attached my logic analyzer to, so that I could feel comfortable that the code is even being loaded into the processor.

Comment: @mah I forgot to mentioned that I am trying to implement a behavioral design, so I though I don't need to the clock.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/vbehave1.html#Example_-_always). A behavioral design means that instead of simply connecting gates and wires together, you work with the flow of data through your module, with the necessary circuits being inferred automatically. But for a CPU design, that data is usually driven by a clock signal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to simulate this code with a Verilog simulator but you will not be able to synthesize this code and load it onto an FPGA. As the comments say, synthesizable Verilog code for FPGAs would have a clock. It should have constructs that look like this

```
always @* begin : combinational_logic
    //...
end

always @(posedge clk) begin : sequential_logic
    //...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The contents of your code array also look wrong. The array dissassembles as:

```
BEQ     $16, $0, 0x4
BEQ     $16, $0, 0x8
J       0x0
BLTZ    $0, 0x4
```